# How to you requirements.txt in python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, requirements.txt

I have requirements.txt including versions of packages and bash script that compiles several python scripts *.py. How to change the compilation command
python3.6 *.py
to use the version of packages in requirements.txt? Or how to create an installation package? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just type the following on the terminal:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```